# What is the horizontal asymptote

Tags: calculus

f (x) = e^(–x)  + 3.

```
(b) What is the y-intercept? 

      my answer is:  (0,4)

(c) What is the domain of f ? 

     my answer is: R all real numbers 

(d) What is the range of f ? 

 my answer is: f>3

(e) What is the horizontal asymptote?
```

does my answers correct and how get horizontal asymptote ?

I need to know why range is larger than 3

I need help to understand this question please

Comment: What happens when $x$ becomes very large ?

Comment: I need to know why range is larger than 3

Comment: For all values of x in R $e^{-x} \gt 0$ so $e^{-x}+3$ is always greater than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your answers a're correct.

A line y=b is a horizontal asymptotic of a function if either limit of f(x) as x tends to $\infty $ is b or limit of f(x) as x tends to -$\infty$ is b.

just apply the limit to y when x tends to infinity.

You will get y=3.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptote of $y=e^x$ is $y=0$, a well know fact.

As we reflect $y=e^x$ in the $y$-axis to get $y=e^{-x}$, the asymptote doesn't change.

As we translate $y=e^{-x}$ $3$ units up, the asymptote also translates $3$ units up. The asymptote becomes $y=3$.

Therefore, the horizontal asymptote of $y=e^{-x}+3$ is $y=3$.